# How to organize multiple flash projects sharing common lib as for classpaths

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Let's say I have multiple projects organized as

```
commonlib
superorg
   org1
     suborg11
     suborg12
   org2
     suborg21
```

How do you declare import and manage classpaths as for classes in commonlib package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either the flash ide or flash builder you can specify global classpaths. That way your import statements are the same across projects without having a million copies of the files.  Heres a tut - http://asgamer.com/2009/easily-use-frameworks-in-multiple-projects-by-setting-a-global-class-path

Comment: Good tut and it also mentions flashdevelop I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your "reused classes" to swc files and add them to your projects. If you are changing your classes often you could setup a Flex Library Project and add the whole library Project to your source in the Project settings. This will keep the files up to date.

Comment: Thanks I'm not using flex but I guess I can do this also in Flash.